# how to pass the specific column of dictionary as input of other function in python

Tags: python, dictionary, input, indexing

Im using a function to parse an excel in python without using libraries but importing an individual script accessing the excel data. my program can read the excel data and with following structure gets the values. I need to access specific columns of the listExcelvalues as follow and pay it to the input of other function :
[actual code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1laiJ.png) 
ive converted the list into the dict but the problem is I dont want to pass all the dictionary as input of other function but instead specific columns.
Any ideas how to do so ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], and don't link to code.  (Also note that just posting the code you have linked to may not actually make for a good MCVE.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you have a structure like this:

```
>>> l=[['a','b','c','d'],['e','f','g','h'],['i','j','k','l'],['m','n','o','p']]
>>> m=list(enumerate(l,0))
>>> m
[(0, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']), (1, ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']), (2, ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l']), (3, ['m', 'n', 'o', 'p'])]
```

Then you can access rows like this. Here is the second row (counting from zero):

```
>>> row=m[2][1]
>>> row
['i', 'j', 'k', 'l']
>>> hrow=m[2]
>>> hrow
(2, ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l'])
```

And columns too. Here is the second (counting from zero) column:

```
>>> col=[]
>>> for r in m:
...     col.append(r[1][2])
>>> col
['c', 'g', 'k', 'o']
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to take a subset of your dict. You may want to try this out:

```
new_dict = {k:v if k in list_of_req_cols for k,v in original_dict.items()}
```